# how to do infinite scroll with Parse Table View Controller?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I want to have infinite scroll, so I figured I would try this code, but I am getting a crash whenever I scroll:

Code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height)) {
        if (![self isLoading]) {
            [self loadNextPage];
        }
        else{

        }
    }
}
```

Crash Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with the error. You are trying to delete a row from the second section but you only have 1 section - so there is no second section.

Comment: If it helps: the second section is section `1`. The first is section `0`.